# How to pass selected div tag id values to single textbox separated by comma using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**Javascript:**

```
function sample(c_id) 
{
    document.getElementById("result").value="";

  var x = document.getElementById("result").value=c_id; 

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="1" onclick="sample(this.id)">one</div>
<div id="2" onclick="sample(this.id)">Two</div>
<input type="text" value="" id="result">
```

Please Help Me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to keep an array of values that have already been added to the input. When you toggle each number, you can have it removed from the array with `splice()` or added to the array with `push()`. Then all you need to do is join the values with a comma, and apply it to the value of your `input`:

```
var taken = [];
function sample(c_id)  {
    var inp = document.getElementById("result");
    var ind = taken.indexOf(c_id);
    if(ind > -1){
        taken.splice(ind,1);
        taken = taken;
    } else {
        taken.push(c_id);
    }
    inp.value = taken.join(',');
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/T2nmd/2/)

Note: It is invalid to start your `id`s with a number. They should start with a letter.

Comment: hi frnd, i onclick same element second time means it should remove from textfield. but it's keep on adding.

Comment: So there should only ever be one of each number?

Comment: in this example, i want to hide id 2. i was hit on word Two,but id 1 is getting hide.

Comment: @user2994953 Apologies, I misunderstood. Edit made.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to do there.

You don't need to pass the id to the function, that can be got with `.id` on a html element. ie. `document.getElementById('someElement').id;`

Try to get your javascript in an external document too, as is you are going to place your code inline then you may as well hard code the id anyway.
(not suggesting that obviously)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong I think you want something like this:

```
$("div").click(function(){
     $("#result").val($("#result").val() + ", " + $(this).attr("id"))
})
```

or if you want something similar to your code just do this:

```
$("div").click(sample($(this).attr("id")));

function sample(c_id) 
{
    document.getElementById("result").val(document.getElementById("result").val() + ", " + c_id);

    var x = document.getElementById("result").val(); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sample(c_id) {
  var result = document.getElementById('result'),
      resultVal = result.value;
  result.value = resultVal == '' || resultVal == undefined ? c_id : resultVal', '+c_id;
}
```